# how to get text from a form to another xml in android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have been trying to figure out of how to get a an input response to another page in Android.
E.g. When a user types in their details like a name, I would like to make this appear in another xml file. 
Right now I  have this in my activity.java.

```
final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
        String name = nameField.getText().toString();
```

This is the form I have:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="Please input your full name" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

How to I make what the the user have typed to save into another xml page that they will be able to see as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't change the actual xml files at runtime. So you won't be inserting this value that you retrieve into an xml file at all.

Each of the objects in an XML layout represents a Java object too. So lets say you had another EditText in your layout:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText2"   
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

<requestFocus />
```

inside your java you could use something like this to put the value from nameField into it.

```
final EditText nameOutput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);  
nameOutput.setText(nameField.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the string in a resource file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string
        name="string_name"
        >text_string</string>
</resources>
```

then reference in your other xml!

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain what you're trying to do isn't possible. If you need to dynamically create a view based off user input it should be done programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The "xml pages" are called [layout resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#load). They are defined at development time and can not be changed during runtime.

You need to programmatically read the edittext value (as you already shown), store it, and then when another edittext is shown insert the value into this edittext.